# Home loan affordability Calculator

Tags: python, for-loop, calculator

I am asked to create a function: maximum_home_loan(PMT, i, n) that calculates the maximum home loan that my customer can afford, if they:

- Can afford to pay an amount, PMT at the end of every YEAR (with the 1st payment made at exactly one year from now)
- at an interest of i% per year compounded annually, and
- pay off the home over a term of n year.

This is how I did it but I think the amount don't add up.

```
def maximum_home_loan(PMT, i, n):
       For i in range(n):
           PMT = PMT*(1 + i)**n
           PV = PMT + i
           PV = PV + PMT
           PV = round(PV, 2)
           return float(PV)
print(maximum_home_loan(15000*12, 0.1045/100, 25))
```

Output: `369523.89`

And the output should actually be: `1578934.73`

What is it that am doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you want to put the return statement? Inside or outside the loop?

Comment: Inside the loop

Comment: Then you have an algorithm design problem and not a typo. Why do you want it to be inside the loop, provided that a return statement terminates the execution of a function?

Comment: Well am still new to Python. And I thought maybe if I put it inside the loop then it would return as it should. What would you suggest I change

Comment: Can you please check the statement "PV=PMT+i". It is not right to add interest rate to an amount.

Comment: @RegiMathew, it's even more "not right", because here `i` is not the interest rate, but the `i` from `for i in range(n)`, an integer.

Comment: Somehow your course doesn't seem to prepare you guys very well to solve this problem, you're [the second one with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52576448/476) today… [:watching_you_emoji:](https://media.giphy.com/media/Ef0TRTKRVGGQw/giphy.gif)

Comment: What would you suggest I do to get an output of 1578934.73?

Comment: I agree with you deceze

Comment: ForceBru if I was to change the i in range to j in range, would that be ok

Comment: @Creeto is the interest rate `.1045` _percent_?

Comment: Yes the interest rate is 0.1045

Comment: @Creeto, if that value is in _percents_, the answer'll be around 4.4 million. Clearly, it's meant to be 10.45%, so you shouldn't divide the value by 100 in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do in your code, so here's another solution.

Let's say at the end of the first year your debt is the following:

Debt<sub>1</sub> = Loan * (1 + i) - PMT

At the end of the second year it'll be:

D<sub>2</sub> = D<sub>1</sub> * (1 + i) - PMT = Loan * (1 + i)<sup>2</sup> - PMT * (1 + (1 + i))

For the Nth year, we get:

D<sub>n</sub> = Loan * (1 + i)<sup>n</sup> - PMT * sum<sub>j=0</sub><sup>n-1</sup> (1+i)<sup>j</sup>

Because D<sub>n</sub> must be zero, you have a formula for `Loan` (I'm pretty sure you can simplify the sum dramatically, <strike>but I can't remember how</strike> see below):

```
def calculate(PMT, i, n):
    return PMT * sum((1+i)**j for j in range(n)) / (1+i)**n
```

You don't really need to calculate the sum with `sum(...)` as there's a formula for this kind of sums:

sum<sub>j=0</sub><sup>n-1</sup> r<sup>j</sup> = (r<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (r - 1)

So, here's this formula in action:

```
def calculate(PMT, i, n: int) -> float:
    return PMT * ((1+i)**n - 1) / i / (1+i)**n

calculate(15_000 * 12, .1045, 25)  # 1578934.728701355
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ForceBru it works fine. Thank you.  So at point on the code would I input. If I'd like to round it off to two decimal places?

Comment: @Creeto, what would you like to round?

Comment: The output #157893.728701355.

Comment: Just like you do in your code: `round(whatever_you_want_to_round, 2)`.

Comment: OK cool and I would have to add it on the code before I return it l? Am I right.

Comment: Thanks a lot ForceBru. You the best :)